# Не все файлы добавляются при создании проекта Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, windowsinstaller

Хочу создать инсталлятор для своего проекта с помощью Visual Sstudio Installer, но он не все файлы зависимостей добавляет. В проекте используется NuGet. Как ему указать, что нужны ещё файлы? И какие файлы вообще нужны? Спасибо.

На скрине выделил те файлы, которые включаются в сборку инсталлера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Версия вашей студии?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов http://prntscr.com/dlrtqi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Studio 2012 есть инсталлер InstallShield. Во вкладке Application Files указываете все стороннии библиотеки и т.д.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Но как мне узнать какие файлы кидать? Методом перебора?

Comment: Если я правильно понял... Все, что в папке bin\Debug\